# Boundaries in Java Gaming, How do "professionals" do it?

Tags: java, boundary, 2d-games

How do professionals do boundaries in a 2D game? The way I do is say I don't want the sprite to move into a certain area:

```
//Example
if ((playerPosX >= 825) && (playerPosX  <= 910)&& (playerPosY >= 170) && (playerPosY <= 255)) {
    //do nothing
}else{
    //move
}
```

But some games out there have a lot of boundaries so I'm wondering, is there an easier way. I don't think there is any way someone would use the above method throughout a whole game, just to block of movement.

**EDIT:** 
My question is mainly regarding a game where you can walk around, similar to Pokemon or final fantasy

Comment: This is more of a design question than anything else, really.

Comment: @fge so its all in the way you design it? Then what would be the best way to design a 2D program to implement easier to make boundaries?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _Real-Time Collision Detection_ by _Christer Ericson_ is a nice overview of 2d & 3d collision detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities come to my mind,

- 1st describe the blocked areas with polygons and do a point in polygone test to determine whether the sprite may move to this position.
- 2nd like in an image manipulation programm create some kind of a mask (layer), where zero bits indicate the position where you can move and ones for the blocked areas. This can be extended to indicated depth see also [z-buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) to partially hide a sprite,

EDIT:

```
if ( mask[ nextY ][ nextX ] == 0 ) {
   currX = nextX;
   currY = nextY;
}
```

assuming all variables are int and mask is a 2d int array.

Comment: are you talking about, i think i saw this somwhere with pokemon but every 25x25 square had  a value and the sprite could only move to the spot if the value was 0 but if it was 1 it couldnt, etc? How would i do this?

Comment: so i would have to create a mask of the whole board/arena/map and check every time i moved?

Comment: @Exikle If you already have a board (25x25) which describes which image (or texture) is placed an each board position you don't need a mask. Simply check board[y][x]

Comment: i don't have a board thats 25x35, its just me drawing a image  on a graphics panel so i was thinking of using our mask idea and for every 5 x,y assigns value because my sprite moves by 5. Therefore I can assigna 0 for movable and 1 for unmovable. DO you think that would work?

Comment: @Exikle Consider a small block 100x4 pixel/units if your position is right before that block and step by 5 you could walk through the block. Event if you step by 5 you need to test that all in between your current and your next position is 'moveable'. Then it would work.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the game.

- In grid-based games, then you often do a *lookup into the grid* whenever a sprite moves to check whether it has moved into a "blocked" area. If so, detect the collision and/or perform some corrective movement of the sprite. This is simple and efficient, the only issue is that it restricts you to designing your level/scenery around a grid structure.
- In games with very dynamic environments (e.g. lots of moving asteroids) then you would typically have a collision detection system based on spatial partitioning (e.g. a *quadtree*) that is used to detect collisions between arbitrary objects. Each object would typically have a *bounding box*.
- In games with complex but fixed geometry defined by vectors, you might pre-compute a BSP-tree and use this for fast detection of collision with scenery. This technique is common in 3D FPS games, but it works in 2D too.

Many games would actually use a combination of the above: e.g. a BSP tree for fixed scenery, and a quadtree for dynamic objects managed by a physics subsystem, for example.

Comment: which category would Pokemon go under because i want to make a game with similiar movements to that.

Comment: Pretty certain Pokemon is grid based. A lot of 2D games are!